How did the cop infer from Uncle Aaron's statement that Miles has been visiting?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, busy with his work, Uncle Aaron answered the door to find a cop:

Cop : Is Miles here?
Uncle Aaron: Nah. Haven't seen him in a while. You, either. What,
like, two years?
Cop : He's been coming here, then, huh?
Uncle Aaron: It's a free country, man.

How did the cop infer from Uncle Aaron's statement that Miles has been visiting?

Because he's not trying too hard to lie.

Jeff is already fully aware that his son, Miles has been seeing his brother, Aaron. Jeff's visit seems to have been prompted by an earlier conversation (also included in the Alternate Universe Cut) in which Mile threatened to drop out of high school and move in with Aaron, which is hardly the sort of thing you'd threaten unless you had a pretty good ongoing relationship.

Miles: Well maybe I'll just save the fun for when I quit school and I move in with Uncle Aaron.





Both brothers are playing their respective parts in a little shadowplay that we can probably title 'I can't believe my brother became a policeman/criminal' that has evidently been going on for quite some time.
Aaron sees Jeff's question as being excessively interrogatory and policemanlike. He play-acts refusing to give up his partner-in-crime, Miles, despite both brothers knowing full well what that real answer is.
